# how to call cleanup a pytest if it fails assert?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Currently I have this `fixture`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def cleanup():
    to_delete = []
    yield to_delete
    for item in to_delete:
        if os.path.exists(item):
            rmtree(item)
```

And here's the test:

```py
def test_fail(cleanup):
    afile = '/tmp/hello'
    os.system(f'touch {afile}')
    assert os.path.exists(afile)
    cleanup.append(afile)
```

The `afile` is removed if assert is true, however, how to remove `afile` even if the assert fail? E.g.:

```py
def test_fail(cleanup):
    afile = '/tmp/hello'
    os.system(f'touch {afile}')
    assert not os.path.exists(afile)
    cleanup.append(afile)
```

I know how about `try`, `except` and `finally` but is there a more elegant solution than?:

```py
def test_fail(cleanup):
    afile = '/tmp/hello'
    os.system(f'touch {afile}')
    try:
        assert not os.path.exists(afile)
    finally:
        cleanup.append(afile)
```

Comment: why not calling `cleanup.append(afile)` right before the assert?. The assert violation causes the .append line to never be called. The code after the `yield` in your fixture will run regardless of whether the assert fails or not. The issue you're having is that the .append(afile) never happens when the assert fails.

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @BorrajaX:

```py
def test_fail(cleanup):
    afile = '/tmp/hello'
    cleanup.append(afile)
    os.system(f'touch {afile}')
    assert not os.path.exists(afile)
```